# Elasticsearch 1.3. - Call custom REST endpoint from Java

Tags: java, rest, elasticsearch

I am currently building an `elasticsearch plugin` which exposes a `REST` endpoint ( starting from this [post](http://blog.brusic.com/2011/09/create-pluggable-rest-endpoints-in.html) )

I can call my endpoint with `curl` like this :

```
curl -X POST 'http://my-es:9200/lt-dev_terminology_v1/english/_terminology?pretty=-d '{ 
   "segment": "database", 
   "analyzer": "en_analyzer"
}
```

My question is how can I call the same endpoint from `java`, using a transport client ? Could you point me to some tutorial ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you take a look [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/client.html#transport-client). It should be a good starting point for you.

Let me sum up :

Considering the following parameters :

```
String clustername = "...";
String clientTransportHost = "...";
Integer clientTransportPort= "...";
String clientIndex = "...";
String indexType = "...";
```

Of course you replace the dots with the settings you wish to use.

Then you define your cluster `Settings`:

```
Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
        .put("cluster.name", clustername).build();
```

You instantiate the TransportClient object :

```
    TransportClient client =  new TransportClient(settings);
client.addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(clientTransportHost, clientTransportPort));
```

You can verify your connection using this method :

```
private void verifyConnection(TransportClient client) {
    ImmutableList<DiscoveryNode> nodes = client.connectedNodes();
    if (nodes.isEmpty()) {
        throw new ElasticsearchException(
                "No nodes available. Verify ES is running!");
    } else {
        log.info("connected to nodes: " + nodes.toString());
    }
}
```

PS: to use the log.info() method you have to instantiate a Logger.

So now you can use the verification method :

```
verifyConnection(client);
```

and once you've done all that you can now per example prepare a search :

```
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch(clientIndex)
            .setTypes(indexType)
                            .addFields("...", "...")
            .setSearchType(SearchType.DEFAULT)
                            .execute()
                            .actionGet();
```

PS : Tested on Elasticsearch 1.3

Comment: Thanks for your response. My problem isn't how to create the transport client, but how to use it to access my own endpoint. I found this great tutorial ( http://jprante.github.io/lessons/2012/03/27/Writing-a-simple-plugin-for-Elasticsearch.html ) which helps but now I have no idea how to get to the client object inside the transport class because what I need is to use existing functionality ...

Comment: May I know why has it been down-voted ? At least if you don't agree with my answer, behave like a respectful adult and comment on why you have down-voted a valid answer.